# iOS: Dismissing and Presenting ModalViewController without access to its Parent ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

**Background:** I would like to dismiss a modalView that I have presented earlier and right away present the same `viewController` that I just dismissed with new information.

**Problem:** I have not been very successful in doing so without an explicit pointer to the parent `ViewController` that presented the first `ViewController` modally. I am trying to write this class that works without messing around with the previous `viewController`'s code.

**Possible lead:** There are couple of things I have been experimenting with:

1.) Trying to get access to the parent `ViewController`, which at this time I don't know how to.

2.) Once access to the parent is gained, I can simply apply the following code:

```
UIViewController* toPresentViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [parentViewControllerAccessor presentModalViewController:toPresentViewController animated:YES];
}];
```

In theory this should work given the access to parent `viewController`. I am open to other ways of doing this.

**Assumption:** You do not have permission to change any code in the parent `ViewController`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code looks like it should work. If you are using iOS 5 there is a `UIViewController` property called `presentingViewController`.

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIViewController *presentingViewController;
```

So you can use this property to get the view controller that presented your modal controller.

**Note:** In iOS 4 `parentViewController` would be set to the presenting controller, so if you are supporting both iOS 4 and 5 you will have to check the OS version first to decide which property to access. In iOS 5 Apple have fixed this so that `parentViewController` is now exclusively used for the parent of contained view controllers (see the section on *Implementing a Container View Controller* in the `UIViewController` documentation).

**Edit:** Regarding accessing `self.presentingViewController` from within the block: By the time the block is called (after the modal view controller is dismissed) the `presentingViewController` property may get set to nil. Remember that `self.presentingViewController` inside the block gives the value of the property when the block is executed, not when it was created. To protect against this do the following:

```
UIViewController* toPresentViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController* presentingViewController = self.presentingViewController;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
{
    [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:toPresentViewController animated:YES];
}];
```

This is necessary not because `self` is gone/dismissed (it is safely retained by the block), but because it is no longer presented, therefore its `presentingViewController` is now nil. It is not necessary to store the `presentingViewController` anywhere else, the local variable is fine because it will be retained by the block.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, I should change this code: `[parentViewControllerAccessor presentModalViewController:toPresentViewController animated:YES];` to `[self.presentingViewController presentModalViewController:croppedPhotoVC animated:YES];`. Sadly, this does not seem to work. Am I understanding something incorrectly?

Comment: This is probably due to how blocks retain objects - it will retain self but not the presenting view controller, so by the time 'self' has been dismissed this property might be set to nil. Set self.presentingViewController to a local variable outside the block then use that variable from within the block.

Comment: That is the same conclusion I have come up with. I might have to make a static variable to hold this such that when `self` get removed, the method will still work. But that looks more like a hack.

Comment: You don't need to store it in a static, the block will retain a local variable for you. I've edited my answer to show you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this using notifications.

For example, fire this notification from outside the modal view when you want it to be dismissed:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"dismissModalView" 
                                                    object:nil 
                                                  userInfo:nil];
```

And then handle that notification inside your modal view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(dismissMe:)
                                                 name:@"dismissModalView" 
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)dismissMe:(NSNotification)notification {
    // dismiss it here.
}
```

Comment: "And then handle that notification inside your modal view:" I am not sure what this suppose to mean, I did explicitly said, I cannot touch the code on the previous viewController that presents this viewController. Unless, I am misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 1):

the solution for ios5:

```
-(void)didDismissModalView:(id)sender {

   // Dismiss the modal view controller
   int sold=0;

   if(sold==0){

      //Cash_sold.delegate = self;
      // Cash_sold.user_amount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",somme];

      Cash_sold = [[CashSoldview alloc] initWithNibName:@"CashSoldview" bundle:nil];
      CGRect fram1 = CGRectMake(200,20,400,400);
      Cash_sold.view.superview.frame = fram1;
      Cash_sold.view.frame=fram1;
      Cash_sold.modalTransitionStyle= UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
      Cash_sold.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

      UIViewController* presentingViewController = self.parentViewController;

      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
      {
         [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:Cash_sold animated:YES];
      }];     
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO 
                         completion:^{
  // instantiate and initialize the new controller
  MyViewController *newViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
  [[self presentingViewController] presentViewController:newViewController
                                                animated:NO
                                              completion:nil];
}];
```